# Using SQL on wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using a plugin I'm able to use PHP on page by using [insert_php] as a tag however, whenever I try using SQL it doesn't seem to work. 
I tried using:

```
global $wpdb;
$prepared = $wpdb->get_row(
    "SELECT SiteID, SiteName
    FROM $wpdb->Site
        WHERE SiteID = 1");

echo $prepared->SiteName;
echo "test";
```

All I'm getting is test on the page and I've tested to see if my sql statement was at fault and it seems to be working fine so I'm guessing there's an issue with $wpdb or the way I'm outputting the data.

Comment: check what `"SELECT SiteID, SiteName FROM $wpdb->Site WHERE SiteID = 1"` really is, and here is your error

Comment: @Peter I have and I get the data I'm looking for. Site is a table I created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WordPress.org has a lot of detailed information in their reference.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row)

I think attempting to refer to `$wpdb->Site` is a likely suspect for why your code is not working. You will need to know the exact fields in the table to pull your information.

[Here is a reference for the wp_site table.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_site) I think you're actually looking for the 'domain' field, not 'sitename'.

Comment: I created a table called Site and dumped data into it, I'm trying the retrieve that data now

Comment: is that table called "Site" in the same database as the rest of the WordPress data?
My suggestion to prevent naming collision between the table with the name "Site" that is already significant to WordPress is to call your table something else, maybe prefix with "my_", eg "my_Site" and try your query against that:
`SELECT SiteID, SiteName FROM $wpdb->my_Site WHERE SiteID = 1`

Comment: It's most useful when there can be an error statement retrieved that describes what is causing the statement to not run.
I suggest next to put these two statements in your php code at the beginning of the block so they enable some diagnostic output:
`ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`
then try and re-run your code. This may or may not output what's causing the problem in the MySQL which I strongly expect is where the problem really is.

Comment: for as much crying as I did about reading the documentation:
[https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors](Here's the switch for enabling output of SQL errors)
Trying turning those on and see what happens.

Comment: Looks like if the table isn't a default wp table then $wpdb->Site should be replaced with `my_site`. Thanks for the help anyway though!

Comment: If my response to your question ultimately lead to the answer you needed, would you consider marking my response as the accepted answer to your question please? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `$wpdb->Site` with the actual name of the table. I also get errors like that at first since `$wpdb->table_name` only works with the default wp tables.

**EDIT**
It should be something like this:
`SELECT SiteID, SiteName FROM Site WHERE SiteID = 1`

Comment: it isn't a default wp table, its one that I added myself

Comment: Okay. You can replace it with the actual table name that you want to use rather than using $wpdb->table_name